# Widget inside a column not scrolling completely when scrolling Scroll-able widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `NestedScrollView` whose body contains a `TabBarView`. And one of the tabs has a column with an image and a scrollable widget(`GridView.builder`). When scrolling this scrollable widget, the images get stuck halfway(as if it was pinned in that position).

Here's the code

```
//home.dart

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(                //this is the image that gets stuck
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: new Image.asset(
              "images/product.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FreshFinds(),    //this is the scrollable widget
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Freshfind.dart 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: GridView.builder(
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 50,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate:
            new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchdata(index),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return buildfake(index);
              else
                return buildcard(snapshot.data, index);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Here is a video of the problem](https://i.imgur.com/P1b2gH5.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `SliverAppBar()` widget alongside with `TabBar()`.

[Here's a resource that might help you](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe)

Comment: I'm not trying to make the image fade away into the header, I just want that image to scroll up.

Comment: Have you tried putting the image inside `TabBarView()` widget instead of a `column()`?. On the Other hand, It's a good UI/UX practice to use the collapsing behavior in the pages that contain TabBars and scrollable lists

Comment: `TabBarView()` takes in children as an argument which is a List of Widget. How am i suppose to do that? 
thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://medium.com/@worthply/flutter-tab-bar-60cb9848ad08)

Comment: If you found it helpful. please mark it as the correct answer. thank you

Comment: I don't think you have understood my problem. I just want to fix the image getting stuck when scrolling a widget that's below it.